# Como puedo desactivar la pantalla táctil en un método

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero desactivar la pantalla táctil hasta que no se acaben de realizar algunas tareas, y no se si se hace con WindowsManager. Podéis darme alguna pista, no tengo código porque nos se por donde empezar.
Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobrecargar el metodo **dispatchTouchEvent** en la actividad de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){      
  return true;
}
```

Si retornas *true* todos los eventos van a estarán deshabilitados.

Si retornas *false* todo volverá a la normalidad.